# Json returning tree model in Spring from list

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jackson

I have a problem with JSON. So I get a user_id from the client side and i must check groups, which is in this user_id.

I get data from database and put it into list.
I have this annotation in xml file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

In output i must return(from server side to client side) for example this tree format of JSON:

```
{'courses':         
    [                 
        {'name':'Informatyka w gospodarce', 'id':'1', 'dates':                         
            [                                 
                {'id':'1', 'code':'bla1', 'name':'PN 13.15'},                                 
                {'id':'2', 'code':'bla2', 'name':'WT 11.15'},                                 
                {'id':'3', 'code':'bla3', 'name':'PT 19.55'},                         
            ]                 
        },                 
        {'name':'Inżynieria oprogramowania', 'id':'2', 'dates':                         
            [                                 
                {'id':'4', 'code':'bla4', 'name':'PN 13.15'},                                 
                {'id':'5', 'code':'bla5', 'name':'WT 11.15'},                                 
                {'id':'6', 'code':'bla6', 'name':'PT 19.55'},                         
            ]                 
        }         
    ] 
}
```

So i have on the output only this:
 {'courses':[]}

The question is: what should  i change, to have on the output this example?
Maybe my interpretation of JSON was bad?

Tree of classes(dependency):
**JsonKursy**
<--**JsonGrupy**
<--**JsonGrupyZajeciowe**

And now this is a POJO clasess which use Jackson:
**JsonKursy**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonSubTypes;

import com.project.Json.JsonGrupy;

@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(JsonGrupy.class) })
public class JsonKursy {
    private List<JsonGrupy> courses;

    public List<JsonGrupy> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(List<JsonGrupy> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
}
```

**JsonGrupy**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonSubTypes;

@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(JsonGrupyZajeciowe.class) })
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class JsonGrupy {

    private String name;
    private int id;
    private List<JsonGrupyZajeciowe> dates;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<JsonGrupyZajeciowe> getDates() {
        return dates;
    }

    public void setDates(List<JsonGrupyZajeciowe> dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
    }
}
```

**JsonGrupyZajeciowe**

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class JsonGrupyZajeciowe {

    private int id;
    private String code;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And my controller which return Json:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getcourses", method = RequestMethod.POST,  produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    JsonKursy wyslijKursy(
            @RequestParam(value = "userid", required = true) int login,
            Model model) {

        List<GrupyZajeciowe> grupyzajeciowe = pobierzGrupyService
                .pobierzGrupyZajeciowe(login);
        int idKursu;
        int i;
        JsonKursy jsonKursy = new JsonKursy();
        JsonGrupy jsonGrupy = new JsonGrupy();
        JsonGrupyZajeciowe jsonGrupyZajeciowe = new JsonGrupyZajeciowe();
        List<JsonGrupy> courses = new ArrayList<JsonGrupy>();
        for (i = 0; i < grupyzajeciowe.size(); i++) {
            idKursu = grupyzajeciowe.get(i).getIdKursu().getIdKursy();

            List<Kursy> kurslist = pobierzGrupyService.pobierzKursy(idKursu);

            for (Kursy kurs : kurslist) {
                List<JsonGrupyZajeciowe> name = new ArrayList<JsonGrupyZajeciowe>();
                for (GrupyZajeciowe grupa : grupyzajeciowe) {
                    // set dla JsonGrupyZajeciowe
                    jsonGrupyZajeciowe.setId(grupa.getIdKursu().getIdKursy());
                    jsonGrupyZajeciowe.setCode(grupa.getKodGrupy());
                    jsonGrupyZajeciowe.setName(grupa.getNazwa());
                }
                jsonGrupy.setName(kurs.getNazwaKursu());
                jsonGrupy.setId(kurs.getIdKursy());
                jsonGrupy.setDates(name);
            }
            jsonKursy.setCourses(courses);
            System.out.println("Test wydruk"+ jsonKursy);
        }

        return jsonKursy;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to add elements to the `courses` List. So the `jsonKursy` object which is serialized to json does not contain any courses.

This can help:

```
courses.add(jsonGrupy);
```

Comment: Yes you have right. Thank you so much. You save my live man. And in forech must add one name.add(jsonGrupyZajeciowe), before jsongrupy add. Thank you very much